# Castle Caladan - why a "pile of stone"?

Tags: meaning

Frank Herbert's Dune book begins with a sentence that describes Castle Caladan as a pile of stone that has been home to 26 generations of Atreides Dukes. Not being a native English speaker, I am  left to wonder as of what does it mean. Does the word "pile" here really mean that the castle was actually a ruin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe we're meant to think the castle is in ruins. "Pile of stone" here is serving as both a literal description — anything made of stone can be described as a pile of stone, it's just that some piles are more, um, *ordered* than others — and as a put-down of stone castles and the social class that lives in them.

Comment: In the context of the novel, it's not so much a put-down as a way to say the castle is *old fashioned*, with everything else being made of plasteel or some sort of handwavium.

Comment: @congusbongus, if you find it necessary to call something old-fashioned, guess what: it's a put-down.

Answer (score 7):

**Pile** can also mean **castle**.

As you say, given the commonest modern meaning of *pile*, Herbert’s phrase evokes the image of something haphazard, maybe even ruined.

But *pile* also has an older meaning, given by the OED as “A stronghold, a castle, esp. a small castle or tower […] Now arch. and rare.”  Though rare, it’s still used in a few well-known phrases — most notably “[ancestral pile](http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22ancestral+pile%22)” — enough so that I’m pretty sure Herbert had this meaning primarily in mind.

However, *heap* has been the primary meaning for long enough that I suspect all modern use of the *castle* sense has become somewhat coloured by connotations of haphazardness, disorder, etc.; certainly it’s generally used for slightly humorous effect. (I seem to recall PG Wodehouse being quite keen on the phrase, though I can’t remember any specific examples.)

Comment: The [Compact Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pile?q=pile), in its entry for _pile_, mentions the second core sense is: "a large imposing building". Because the phrase says: "pile of stone", and not "pile of stones", that suggests it is something whole, unified, single and made of stone.

Answer (score 1):

Though "pile of stones" literally implies a ruin, the author in your example uses it to express his disdain about Castle Caladan, or at least to describe it in a humorous way.  He thinks it's nothing special.